# Prevent infinite loop when updating attributes within after_commit, :on => :create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, callback

I create an infinite callback loop when I need to update an attribute during an `after_commit, :on => :create`. It only occurs if I need to update an attribute of the object during this callback, though. Is there a way to prevent this? Can I somehow force a model to reload itself so it knows that it is performing an update rather than a create?

```
class Doc < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_commit :generate, :on => :create

  ...

  def generate
    # some logic here that requires this model to be saved in the db

    self.update_attributes(:filename => filename) # Infinite loop begins here.
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you share the server logs generated. Also, it would be great if you share the complete `generate` method.

Comment: I have encountered the same problem, and I think it's a bug. `after_commit` should be trigged only `on: :create` as the declaration, but in fact it's trigged even it's updated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the method `update_column` that will skip all callbacks of your model:

```
self.update_column(:filename, filename)
```

Or you could use the method `update_all`, wich follows the same behavior

```
self.class.where('id = ?', self.id).update_all(:filename => filename)
```

And last but not least, my personal favorite:

```
self.filename = filename
self.send(:update_without_callbacks)
```

This one makes it pretty clear that all callbacks are been ignored, what is very helpful

---

Also, as a different alternative, you coud use `after_create` instead of `after_commit` if you want to run  the `generate` method only when a new record is saved

Comment: Just an FYI, update_without_callbacks was removed in Rails 3. But the first two recommendations still seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

The problem will be `update_attributes` will initiate the `after_commit` callback you've used

As mentioned by Rafael, you'd either need to use a callback not triggered by `update_attributes`, or use an update method which negates callbacks:

---

**[`update_column`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_columns)** does not initiate callbacks - `self.update_column(filename: filename)`

---

**[`after_create`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)** only fires when you create a record (not update) - `after_create :generate`

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug, see the Github issue https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/16286