# rails update_attribute loops forever

Tags: ruby-on-rails

## update_attribute call creates forever loop.

What could be the cause?
Maybe a variand of this:
[Prevent infinite loop when updating attributes within after_commit, :on => :create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567358/prevent-infinite-loop-when-updating-attributes-within-after-commit-on-crea)

### ruby --version

`ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-linux]`

### commands

```
rails new loop
cd loop
bundle install
bundle exec rails g scaffold User
bundle exec rails db:migrate
bundle exec rails g migration add_name_to_users name:string
bundle exec rails db:migrate
```

### add the following to app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  before_create: create_temp_name

  def create_temp_name
    update_attribute :name, 'temp name'
  end
end
```

### Run `bundle exec rails s`,access `http://localhost:3000/users/new` and press the create button.

### Result:

```
SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
  
app/models/user.rb:5:in `create_temp_name'
app/models/user.rb:5:in `create_temp_name'
```

### bundle list

- actioncable (5.1.1)
- actionmailer (5.1.1)
- actionpack (5.1.1)
- actionview (5.1.1)
- activejob (5.1.1)
- activemodel (5.1.1)
- activerecord (5.1.1)
- activesupport (5.1.1)
- addressable (2.5.1)
- arel (8.0.0)
- bindex (0.5.0)
- builder (3.2.3)
- bundler (1.14.6)
- byebug (9.0.6)
- capybara (2.13.0)
- childprocess (0.7.0)
- coffee-rails (4.2.1)
- coffee-script (2.4.1)
- coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
- concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
- erubi (1.6.0)
- execjs (2.7.0)
- ffi (1.9.18)
- globalid (0.4.0)
- i18n (0.8.1)
- jbuilder (2.6.4)
- listen (3.1.5)
- loofah (2.0.3)
- mail (2.6.5)
- method_source (0.8.2)
- mime-types (3.1)
- mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
- mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
- minitest (5.10.2)
- multi_json (1.12.1)
- nio4r (2.0.0)
- nokogiri (1.7.2)
- public_suffix (2.0.5)
- puma (3.8.2)
- rack (2.0.2)
- rack-test (0.6.3)
- rails (5.1.1)
- rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
- rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
- railties (5.1.1)
- rake (12.0.0)
- rb-fsevent (0.9.8)
- rb-inotify (0.9.8)
- ruby_dep (1.5.0)
- rubyzip (1.2.1)
- sass (3.4.23)
- sass-rails (5.0.6)
- selenium-webdriver (3.4.0)
- spring (2.0.1)
- spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
- sprockets (3.7.1)
- sprockets-rails (3.2.0)
- sqlite3 (1.3.13)
- thor (0.19.4)
- thread_safe (0.3.6)
- tilt (2.0.7)
- turbolinks (5.0.1)
- turbolinks-source (5.0.3)
- tzinfo (1.2.3)
- uglifier (3.2.0)
- web-console (3.5.1)
- websocket (1.2.4)
- websocket-driver (0.6.5)
- websocket-extensions (0.1.2)
- xpath (2.0.0)

Comment: from where are you calling this method 'create_activation_digest'

Comment: It must be triggering some callback in the `User` model.

Comment: yea, probably before or after update.

Comment: Thanks for posting. The curious thing is pry's `next` command does not take me anywhere but keeps the execution point at `update_attribute` method call. So, it does not look like `create_activation_digest` is caught in callback loop. Well, I can simply call `@user.save` in controller's create action to avoid this, but gosh ruby's magic is too much for the uninitiated .

Comment: Could you include the relevant code in users_controller.rb?

Comment: hi kcdragon, updated. I have successfully recreated the problem in a new app;see the edit2. Looks like update_attribute call in call backs is not a good idea, which is fine but hmm what's causing this weirdness?

Comment: @TastyCatFood  `update_attribute` is an alias of `save`, therefore you're recursively calling the `before_save` callback causing an infinite loop / stack overflow. see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to call `update_attribute` in the callback, because the `save` method will be called after the `before_create` callback executes. You can just assign the value like `name = 'temp_name'` in the callback, and allow it to be saved during object creation. `update_attribute` is an alias of `save`, so you're in effect saving the initialized object before the save function is called again when the callback completes, causing an infinite loop / stack overflow.

To help understand this, if you instantiate a new blank object in the rails console, then run update_attribute on one of it's attributes, you'll notice that the object is saved/assigned an id:

```
# rails c

user = User.new
user.persisted?
  => false
user.update_attribute('name', 'Nick')
user.persisted?
  => true
```

So by calling update_attribute, you're invoking an additional instance of the `before_create` callback, because before the model allows the object to be saved to the database during the `update_attribute` call, it invokes the `before_create` callback.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It took so long but it's still nice to know what exactly went wrong.

Comment: No problem dude! Glad to have helped : ) Sucks being stuck inside an infinite loop